# Is there a backwards compatibility break in proc_close with PHP 7?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, php-7, proc-open

It looks like I just found an undocumented PHP7 backwards compatibility break, before I run off the report I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

Here's the code:

```
$proc = proc_open("pwd",[1=>['pipe','w']], $pipes);
if(!is_resource($proc)) {
    exit("bad proc\n");
}
$node = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
$status = proc_close($proc);
var_dump($status);
```

This returns `int(0)` in `PHP 5.6.11-1+deb.sury.org~utopic+1 (cli)` and `int(-1)` in `PHP 7.0.2 (cli) (built: Feb 29 2016 16:53:37) ( NTS )`.

The changelog doesn't show any changes for PHP7 in `proc_open`, `fclose` or `proc_close` so in theory these functions shouldn't have changed their behaviour.

Is there something else I'm overlooking? Why is this failing in PHP7?

---

Amended code:

```
$proc = proc_open("pwd",[1=>['pipe','w'],2=>['pipe','w']], $pipes);
$stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
var_dump($stdout);
$stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
var_dump($stderr);
fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
$status = proc_close($proc);
var_dump($status);
```

Both php5.6 and php7 print correct working directory and empty string for stderr. php5.6 still returns exit code 0, and php7 exit code -1. Adding pipe 0 (stdin) makes no difference.

Comment: How did the output from `pwd` differ in the two cases? Have you checked `stderr`?

Comment: @Andrea If I `var_dump($node)` it comes out the same in both cases (correctly prints current working directory). I haven't checked stderr yet... `pwd` doesn't print anything to stderr in my terminal, but I guess I can add an extra pipe and check it. But if there was a process error it should return 1-255 not -1.

Comment: Well, no one told me I'm doing something wrong so I submitted a bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71804